# mapreduce to find multiple max values

Tags: mongodb, pandas, pymongo

Trying to understand how to do this with map_reduce.  Currently, I do a find to pull a whole collection into one big pandas dataframe.  That df contains something like this:

```
project     ep     seq     shot     layers          totalframes
showA     sh18     17120     10     cnt_chr_set     128
showA     sh18     17040     70     shd_chr_set     288
showA     sh18        80    460     chr_rim         131
showA     sh18     17120     20     chr_vol_lgt     120
showA     sh18     17120     10     set_all         128
showA     sh18     17120     20     cnt_chr_set     120
showA     sh18     17120     20     cnt_chr_set     130
showA     sh18     17120     20     cnt_chr_set       3
showA     sh18     17120     20     cnt_chr_set       1
showA     sh18     17120     10     set_all_ani     128
showA     sh18     17120     20     set_all_ani     120
showA     sh18     17040     70     set_all         288
showA     sh18     17120     10     shd_chr_set     128
showA     sh18     17120     20     shd_chr_set     120
showA     sh18     18150     20     chr_ben_steam     3
showA     sh18     18150     20     chr_whi_steam     3
showA     sh18     18150     20     chr_bil_steam     3
showA     sh18     17040     70     chr_sal_steam   288
```

What I actually need to do, is find the MAX totalframes for each layer of a shot.  The resulting dataframe, should contain only one of each layer for a shot.  eg:

```
showA     sh18     17120     20     chr_vol_lgt     120
showA     sh18     17120     20     cnt_chr_set     130
showA     sh18     17120     20     set_all_ani     120
```

I've been actually trying to get to this point just with pandas, but it seems like it's too much data to work with.  Pulling only exactly the info I need from mongodb into the dataframe seems like the right way to go, but I don't know where to start with map_reduce.

Pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

MapReduce is unnecessary here, most likely, just use aggregation framework:

```
{ "$group" : { "_id" : { "l": "$layers",
                         "s": "$shots"
                       }, 
               "maxframes" : {"$max" : "$totalframes"}
} }
```

Not sure if you care about the other fields, if so you can add them to the "_id" grouping.  You can use `$project` to rename fields in another stage, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

When one look at your data suggests it would be a simple 'group by' in SQL, map reduce is probably going to unnecessary

I'm thinking an aggregation query, something roughly like this:

```
{$group : {"_id" : "$layers", "max_totalframes" : {"$max" : "$totalframes"}}}
```

This should return the highest totalframes for each layers item. If I understood your question correctly, that is what you're looking for

Comment: Wouldn't this group the layers, but ignore the shots?  I have a limited # of layer names, but thousands of different shot names.  Need to find the max for each layer for every shot.

Comment: You're right. I think you'll want to do an aggregation with combination of a $sort by layers:1, totalframes:-1 and a $first. I can put one together if I have time tomorrow